# UIDocument loadFromContents contents is corrupt EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, icloud

I have been having this issue for days trying to resolve it, with no luck.

I have a UIDocument that syncs over iCloud,
Here is the methods

```
- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [archiver encodeObject:note forKey:@"note"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    return data;
}

- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(NSData *)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    NSLog(@"%@", [contents bytes]);
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:contents];
    name = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    note = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"note"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    return YES;
}
```

As you can see I do a NSLog on the contents, most of the time, everything is fine. And it loads properly, however when the data is corrupt, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS even just doing the NSLog.

Somehow the data in the ubiquity container gets corrupted, however it does not spread to the other devices, all other devices will load the content fine. Deleting the app from the device does not fix it. Only if I resave the document on another device does it end up working.
I am using ARC so that shouldn't be the issue.
I have checked the NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey which returns true.

Obviously I want to figure out what is causing the corruption in the first place, but how can I find out if the data isn't valid so that the app won't crash?

Comment: Had the issue myself and today found the following answer which looks like it nailed it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11271599/474794

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS using iCloud on multiple devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743517/exc-bad-access-using-icloud-on-multiple-devices)

Comment: Thanks, I actually already saw that answer and as I posted in my question I already checked the NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey and it returned true. Plus it is only like a 1k file so I wouldn't still be getting that error hours later

Comment: Only because the file is small, doesn't mean it should be available hours later, iCloud could have whatever issues. Sorry, I overlooked that you are already checking the download flag. Are you able to reproduce this? I sadly had no luck reproducing this and all I have is a few crash reports.

Comment: No can't seem to make it reproducible, although it seems to happen most often when I do my "localToiCloud" function (so user has iCloud turned off, then if they enable it, it will move any non duplicated documents to the ubiquity container, and overwrite anything that is newer. It seems more often that not when I do the overwriting that it gets corrupted but not always